# Can I setup a server which writes down video stream to a file?

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp

I think this is not a programming question but I'm not sure where to ask.

I have an RTSP video stream which I would like to receive and write down to a video file while it transmits.

I have found several servers which allow to re-stream such an RTSP stream but I have not found anything which would allow me to write down a video file as I receive it. Something like they have in the [Bambuser](http://bambuser.com/) even more preferably, free.

Could someone, please, advise something to achieve that?

**Edited just to be more clear:**

I want to be able to turn on/off recording when, say, I see something interesting in the video. So my use case is: user sits before the screen, watches the live video from, say, ip-camera, and, when he sees something of interest he starts recording that particular fragment, then stops recording. No further editing is needed. So I wonder if there is any software for that or any library with which I can build it

Answer (score 1):

> **Possible Duplicate**:
>
> [rtsp stream capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932389/rtsp-stream-capturing)

If I have understood your problem correctly, given an RTSP resource (e.g. `rtsp://example.com/media.mp4`) you want to *download*, so to speak, that resource on your computer. right?

Depending on the availability for your operating system, there are several tools which you could use. For example take a look at [VLC](http://www.videolan.org)'s tutorial on how to [receive and save a stream](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch06.html).

For a short tutorial you can also take a look [here](http://loopkid.net/articles/2011/04/15/dumping-an-rtsp-mp4-stream) or check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946391/2295964) out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Ideally, I would want something that would allow me to see and to save an rtsp stream at the same time, with some web interface to turn on/off saving to a file. I have no idea if such things exist.

Comment: So you could somehow edit the original file? In other words to record only those parts you want?

Comment: Just to be able to turn on/off recording when, say, I see something interesting in the video. So my use case is: user sits before the screen, watches the live video from, say, ip-camera, and, when he sees something of interest records that particular fragment. No further editing is needed. So I wonder if there is any software for that or any library with which I can build it